# How to change the app id in googleplaystore url link

Tags: android

I have published the app in google play store here the url be like `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.after2.svirtzone.after2_gradle&hl=en`. In here `i need to change id as com.after+2`. I have registered the app package name with google and face book developer console for `google and facebook signin` and `gcm`. Am i want to rename the package name with facebook and google developer console too? .What i have to do to change the app id in playStore

this is my bulid.gradle

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.after2.svirtzone.after2_gradle"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

this is from  my menifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.after2.svirtzone.after2_gradle">
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot rename the app you published.But can publish the renamed app as a new app.After publishing you will have a new url with the renamed app name.

Answer (score 0):

After published app,if you  changed package name means its consider as a new application.

**Package Name** The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual package name parts may only start with letters.

Once you publish your application, you cannot change the package name. The package name defines your application's identity, so if you change it, then it is considered to be a different application and users of the previous version cannot update to the new version.

More details [Refer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)